# Permission Denied when trying to play audio- R

Tags: r, audio, wav

I'm trying to play a soundfile using seewave's listen option, and getting a permission denied error

```
library(seewave)
v.sound <-sin(2*pi*440 * seq(0,1,length.out = 8000))
f <- 8000
seewave::listen(v.sound, f= f)
```

```
sh: /var/folders/gg/5v7wvcts2jg4zm40s7r9fgqc0000gn/T//RtmpDWOqTa/tuneRtemp.wav: Permission denied
```

I get the same result using when using tuneR's play() function to read .wav files. I tried the suggestion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23310005/permission-denied-when-playing-wav-file) to and got the same results.

I'm using macOS High Sierra 10.13.6

Answer (score 3):

So it turns out the packages 'sound' and 'tuneR' both use the setWavePlayer() function. I was able to solve this pretty easily with this quick fix

```
tuneR::setWavPlayer('/usr/bin/afplay')
```